# Упрощение регулярного выражения для std::regex

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Проверяю строку на полное соответствие шаблону с помощью std::regex_match. При длине строк >120 символов может появится исключение о превышении сложности проверки полного соответствия(error_complexity) или о переполнении стека (error_stack). Второе можно исправить с помощью `#define _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT  n`

На данный момент регулярное выражение удалось упростить так:

```
regex r("(\"([A-Z_]+((,(?!-)|\\|(?!-))?))+->[A-Z_]+\"(,(?!$)|$))+");
```

Пример валидной строки:

```
"A_B,K->CN","CN|K,A_B->D_L","MA,AM|AP->P_A",...
```

Возможные ошибки которые должны считаться **невалидными**:

```
"A_B,,K->CN","CN||K,A_B->D_L"

"A_B,K->CN"","CN|K,A_B->D_L"

"A_B,K->CN",,"CN|K,A_B->D_L"
```

Как еще можно упростить регулярное выражение?

Comment: Может, исходник по запятым порезать и проверять каждый кусок отдельно? Там и распараллелить можно попытаться.

Comment: как минимум можно заменить на `("([A-Z_]+(([,\|](?!-))?))+->[A-Z_]+"(,(?!$)|$))+` (я убрал лишние слеши, в с++ давно есть raw строки). С хвостом также можно поработать